# How do I create a playlist for RealPlayer?

Tags: playlist, realplayer

I want to create a playlist in RealPlayer through a Perl script to avoid every time opening the ReaPlayer for an audio or video file.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Smil](http://search.cpan.org/~cdawson/Smil-0.898/lib/Smil.pm) module from CPAN.
RealPlayer supports SMIL.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to construct the right text in the file. Lucas Gonze put together a nice [survey of playlist formats](http://gonze.com/playlists/playlist-format-survey.html), including the ones you need for RealPlayer.